# How to make it so a string has to start with a capital letter with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
      <form action="http://www.cknuckles.com/cgi/echo.cgi" method="get" name="logOn">
              User Name:<br />
          <input type="text" name="userName" size="25" /><br />
              Password:<br />
          <input type="password" name="pw" size="25" /><br />

          <input type="submit" value="Log In" onClick="validate()"/> 
      </form>
```

Thats my HTML, I have figured out how to only get alpha numerical data into the fields, but how do I get it to only allow a User Name that starts with a capital?

```
      <script language="javascript">

              </script>
```

Comment: +1 For A Self-Referencing Title!

Comment: what is the content of the validate() function?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to check this is with a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
function(str){
    return /^[A-Z]/.test(str);
}
```

returns `true` when the input string starts with a capital, false otherwise. (This particular regular expression - the bits between the // characters - is saying, 'match the start of the string followed by any single character in the range A-Z'.)

In terms of your HTML above, we'll need the contents of the validate() function to determine where the regex match needs to go.

Comment: Im a complete noob at this - how could I write that in a full function using my HTML above?

Comment: editing answer now in response to comments. Thanks for the catch, cw =)

Answer (score 0):

In your validate function, use a regex `match` like this:

```
 if (titleString.match(/^[A-Z]/))
     <ok>
```

Comment: I tried that is well - didnt work for me, could you write the complete function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var letter = str[0];
if (letter !== letter.toUpperCase()){
   //not uppercase!
}
```

Comment: I had a go at that with a similar approach, for the sake of supporting non-standard latin characters, but you need to do far more than just that to make that validate, such as rule out numbers, other random characters etc.

Comment: doing an additional test with `toLowerCase()` ought to weed out any of the non-letter stuff, although you probably want to flip your conditions around. `var isok = (letter===letter.toUpperCase() && letter!==letter.toLowerCase());`

Answer (score 0):

This will check to see if the username entered starts with a capital letter, and is followed by 5 - 24 alphanumeric characters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function validate() {

                var the_input = document.getElementById('userName').value;

                if (!the_input.match(/^[A-Z]([A-Z]|[a-z]|[0-9]){5,24}$/)) {

                    alert('Your username must begin with a capital letter, and contain between 6 and 25 alphanumeric characters.');

                    return false;

                } else {

                    alert('Welcome!');

                    return true;

                }

            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="http://www.cknuckles.com/cgi/echo.cgi" method="get" name="logOn">

            User Name:<br />

            <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" size="25" /><br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="password" name="pw" size="25" /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="Log In" onclick="return validate();"/>

        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

As an aside, it should be noted that this will not work if the user has javascript turned off - you may wish to have some server-side validation instead  (or in addition) as a fail-safe.

Comment: Did you include the `id="userName"` in the input field, as well as the `validate()` function?

Comment: What is that [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript) doing in the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: @Quentin I don't follow, what do you mean by label?

Comment: @Guffy — `javascript:`, it provides a label for a later `continue` statement (for example), but you have no loop, so it does nothing.

Comment: @Quentin - Gotcha, edited accordingly! Out of curiosity, does the script work for you, aside from th label?