# My code does not work - im trying to see if the first letter is a capital :: JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to see if the first letter of a string is a Capital.

Here is my HTML

```
Test:<br/>
<input type="text" name="Testr" size="25" />
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
var namer=document.logOn.Testr.value;

if(/[^A]/.test(namer)){             
     alert("CHOMP CHOMP");
        return false;
}
```

I dont understand why my code doesnt work?

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 4):

Your regular expression looks for anything that's not capital "A".  Try:

```
if (/^[A-Z]/.test(namer)) {
  // starts with a capital letter
}
else {
  // starts with something else
}
```

What I changed was:

- The "^" needed to be outside the "[]" to indicate that you're checking the start of the value
- The range needed to cover all the upper-case letters, not just "A"

Note that if you're interested in matching upper-case characters from elsewhere in the Unicode space, you'll have to include those explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex instead:

```
/^[A-Z]{1}/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is incorrect.  You're checking that namer doesn't begin with the capital letter A.  You need to use a range instead:

```
if(/^[A-Z]/.test(namer)){             
     alert("CHOMP CHOMP");
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the answer from this question: [How to make it so a string has to start with a capital letter with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256550/how-to-make-it-so-a-string-has-to-start-with-a-capital-letter-with-javascript)

you're only testing the capital letter A...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(/^[A-Z]/.test(namer)){             
     alert("CHOMP CHOMP");
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Testr" size="25" />
```

...

```
var namer = document.getElementById('Testr').value;

if(/^[A-Z]/.test(namer)){
    alert("CHOMP CHOMP");
    return false;
}
```